# Login form missing styling

Tags: form

Does anyone have any clue why my login page is missing styling. Seems like encoding trouble, but this has been perfectly fine before. I also checked the CSS, which has alot of scrambled content... check out the screenshots.﻿

Front end:

[image]

Weird CSS file:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the garbled CSS, you need to disable `zlib.output_compression` in your php.ini file.

Seems to be a [PHP bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=23488).

Comment: Yup, this was the problem. Thanks a bunch, Brad :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried clearing your cache?

> Control Panel > Settings > Clear Caches

Looks like a template or something might have gotten screwed up. That's definitely a weird CSS file.

Comment: The problem is that I can't log in either. Emptying the storage folder didn't help..

Comment: Edit: Emptying cache folder returns this first: `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 56 bytes) in /data1/www/moelven/quarter/craft/app/framework/base/CComponent.php on line 266` and after a refresh then it gives me the following: `Internal server error: Unable to register extension "Slugify Twig Extension" as extensions have already been initialized.` before it returns to the non-styled form.

Comment: Something is definitely screwed up in your system. I'd suggest emailing **support@buildwithcraft.com**... Include (1) an export of your database, (2) all of your template files zipped up, and (3) a description of the problem **with a link to this SE page**. Good luck, please report back here and let us know what you find out!